# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jersey.webservice.Login cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

I already done a lot of search and I can't fix this.

I'm bulding a Web Service with Tomcatv7.0, Jersey and Eclipse.

This is the root cause:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jersey.webservice.Login cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)`
 
...

This is the exception:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: Class org.jersey.webservice.Login is not a Servlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)`

...

I have a simple class:

```
package org.jersey.webservice;

import ...

@Path("/login")  public class Login {

    // This method is called if HTML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Andre" + "</title>"
                + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Andree" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
    }
}
```

And this is my web.xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <display-name>org.jersey.andre</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Andre Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jersey.webservice.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Andre Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>`
```

The Login class is in the package org.jersey.webservice and in WEB-INF/lib I´ve imported the needed jars (jersey-api, jersey-core, etc...).

Do you find anything wrong?
I follow the documentation and this isn´t working. Damn!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What tutorial were you reading? This is not the right way to declare a Jersey web service. It is indeed not directly a `Servlet` as the exception is trying to tell you. You need to declare the main Jersey servlet container with an init param pointing to the package containing the webservice classes.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Andre Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jersey.webservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Andre Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also note that you should map it on the path `/rest/*` not the name `/rest`, otherwise you won't be able to use path information like `http://example.com/context/rest/foo/bar` and so on.

#### See also:

- [Jersey's own User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html)
- [Oracle's JAX-RS with Jersey tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/index.html) (part of [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/))
- [Vogela's JAX-RS with Jersey tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, consider choosing something else than `org.jersey` as main package. E.g. `org.andreelias`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. It´s working now! I really don't give much attention to the init param.
Thanks! Cheers